# iOS 13 Public Beta 2 - Combine.Future "dyld: Symbol not found"

Tags: ios, swift, beta, combine

When launching my app on an iPad running the iOS 13 beta 2 build I receive a SIGABRT. This build works fine on the simulator

`dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7Combine6FutureCyxq_GAA9PublisherAAMc`
`Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Combine.framework/Combine`

I thought maybe it was a linking problem, but Combine does not appear in the list of libraries available to link.

Does anyone have a work around or am I sunk until the next beta?

---

Here is my code snippet:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var future: AnyPublisher<String, Error>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        future = ViewController.makeNumberString(50)
        future?.sink { result in
            print("FUTURE DONE: \(result)")
        }
    }

    static func makeNumberString(_ number: Int) -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
        return Combine.Future<Int, Error> { complete in
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                complete(.success(number))
            }
        }
        .map { number in
            return "\(number)"
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean SIGABRT which is often caused by not having a IBOutlet or IBAction connected from a storyboard to your code. In other cases, I've found adding an Exception Breakpoint and Swift Error Breakpoint in Xcode's Breakpoint Navigator will stop execution at the offending code.

Comment: I was incorrect about the OS Version. I'm running public beta 2. 

I've got a a sample project that's crashing for me with the same error
https://github.com/zerocustom1989/futuretest_ios13b3

Running iPad OS13 17A5508m (public beta 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xcode Beta and your iPadOS/iOS Beta version should match. Otherwise it can happen that Combine can not be linked to your application.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Could this be a mismatch between the public beta build and the dev beta build of Xcode?

Comment: Yes. If you use iOS 13 beta 2 you should also use Xcode 11 beta 2.

Comment: This was the key. I changed my iPad to use the 3rd developer beta instead of the 2nd public beta. The app launched fine without even needing to be reinstalled from Xcode. 

<sigh> thanks for the push!

Comment: How about when releases are out of sync?  Currently iOS beta 6 is out, and xcode 11 beta 5 is latest.  I get this crash.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested the following (as well as your code snippet) in Xcode 11.0 beta 3 (11M362v) running on iPad Pro w 13.0 (17A5522f), it worked fine.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("viewDidLoad")

        _ = bar().sink { value in
            print("sink", value)
        }
    }

    // some old asynchronous method

    func foo(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            completion(true)
        }
    }

    // `Future` promise for that old async method

    func bar() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        Future { promise in
            self.foo { value in
                promise(.success(value))
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: If I paste this into my view controller it fails too with the same symbol not found error. I've tried reunzipping Xcode and using a fresh version, but that didn't work. 

You didn't need to 'embed' or manually link the Combine framework, right?

I'll file a report with feedback assistant I guess. Was hoping this was just a silly oversight.

Comment: @orion - Nope. Just created blank project and added the above. Are you using Xcode 11 beta 3?

Comment: Yea :/ Version 11.0 beta 3 (11M362v)